# how to convert python string's every char, add 1 to their ascii, and store to a new string

Tags: python

I want to encode a string to a new string by add one to every char's ascii, and store to a new string, but I get some error, 
my code like this:

```
def encode(data):
    new_data = ''
    try:
        for c in data:
            new_data += chr(ord(c) + 1)
    except Exception as e:
        print "encode error(%s)" % e 
return new_data
```

I get the exception: chr() arg not in range(256), can anybody help me?

Comment: Depending on the content of data, the encoding may be not 'ascii', so chr() will not work. What are you passing to encode()?

Comment: `chr(255)`  is a latin  small letter y`ÿ` so if you add 1 to it you are no longer in range 256.  You can only add 1 to it if you have ascii values < 255 and even then you would need to decode to see something other than `�`  for values  > 240 unless you use unichr

Comment: maybe it is a good way to solve this porblem by judge the ascii whether greate 255, but if in C language, you can add 1 to any char even the char ascii is 255, I don't know if there any way like this in python @PadraicCunningham

Comment: what would you want to do with chars whose ord is > 254?

Comment: I just want to add 1 to every char without judge the the ascii @PadraicCunningham

Comment: just use unichr if you want to be able to have ords > 254, what kind of input are you taking?

Comment: If you were using python3  your code would work

Comment: well, I just want to design a http proxy client(writen by python) who encodes data from browser and decode data from remote proxy server(writen by C), like this: browser --> proxy client(encode data) --> remote proxy server

Comment: oh, my python version is 2.7

Comment: yes, I copy from vim by ctrl+c and paste here ctrl+v @KevinJ.Chase

Answer (score 0):

```
def increment_ascii(string):
    if not isinstance(string, str):
        raise TypeError("Expected <class 'str'>, got {}".format(type(string)))
    ret = list()
    for char in string:
        try:
            char = chr(ord(char) + 1)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        ret.append(char)
    return ''.join(ret)
```

Comment: Why is `string` reversed?

Comment: if char's ascii is 255, it will raise some exception like this code

Comment: Actually you should be able to go up to 1114111 before you get a `ValueError`, but anyway I've added that in. Kevin, actually I don't know what I was thinking at the time :P fixed that up now.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem like this, just judge the ascii if great 255 or not:

```
def encode(data):
    data = bytearray(data)
    try:
       for i in range(len(data)):
           if data[i] < 255:
               data[i] = data[i] + 1 
           elif data[i] == 255:
               data[i] = 0 
           else:
               print "data encode not right(%d)" % data[i]
    except Exception as e:
       print "encode error(%s)" % e 

    return data
```

thank you all of you above.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already answered this, but since I typed it all...

You're asking the impossible:  A byte stores 256 possible values, and you will occasionally need the 257th.  (Note that "bytes" is *not* the same as "ASCII".)

More specifically, you can't replace the bytes of a valid ASCII string (or many other strings) with arbitrary other bytes, and expect the result to still be a valid string in the original encoding.  As you've discovered, even adding 1 is arbitrary enough.

(Since you mentioned C:  Yes, you can add 1 to any `char` (really a byte).  C achieves this by occasionally [producing the wrong answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).  This is a bug, if not in C, at least in your C program.)

So consider your two incompatible goals --- encrypting a string to an unreadable binary blob, versus converting a valid string into another also-valid string --- and decide which one is more important to you.

Here's my suggestion for converting any byte --- ASCII or not --- to some other byte.  They key is to *rotate* 1, not add 1.  That last value has to map to *something*, and the usual answer in this case is to "wrap around" back to 0.

If you really want to stick to ASCII (which is only the lower half of your 256 byte values), you probably want to shuffle only the *printable* characters.  In that case, you would want to do a similar rotation, but only on values from `0x20` up to but not including `0x7f`.  People's definition of "printable" varies, but this will include all the usual letters, numbers, and punctuation, while leaving tabs (`0x09`) and deletes (`0x7f`) alone.

My sample code below rotates spaces (`0x20`) like any other printable character.  You could leave spaces intact by declaring the "printables" to start one after the space character: set `p_start` to `0x21` instead of `0x20`.

Here's an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


def rotated(s, rotation=1):
    """
    Returns a new string with all characters in the given string
    rotated by rotation (1, by default).

    The result might or might not be a valid string, depending on the
    encoding in use.
    """
    old_ords = [ord(char) for char in s]
    new_ords = [(ordinal + rotation) % 256 for ordinal in old_ords]
    new_string = "".join(chr(new_ordinal) for new_ordinal in new_ords)
    return new_string


def ascii_rotated(s, rotation=1):
    """
    Returns a new string with all "printable" characters in the given
    ASCII string rotated by rotation (1, by default).

    Spaces (0x20) are considered printable; tabs (0x09) and deletes (0x7f)
    are not.
    """
    p_start = 0x20  # Space
    p_end = 0x7f  # Delete
    p_span = p_end - p_start
    old_ords = [ord(char) for char in s]
    new_ords = []
    for ordinal in old_ords:
        if (p_start <= ordinal < p_end):
            new_ordinal = p_start + ((ordinal - p_start + rotation) % p_span)
        else:
            new_ordinal = ordinal
        new_ords.append(new_ordinal)
    new_string = "".join(chr(new_ordinal) for new_ordinal in new_ords)
    return new_string


def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if args:
        for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
            print(rotated(arg))
            print(ascii_rotated(arg))
    else:
        # Demonstrate rotation of all 256 possible bytes.
        # (Redirect this to a file if your terminal can't handle it.)
        all_bytes = range(0x100)
        all_bytes_as_str = "".join(chr(b) for b in all_bytes)
        print(all_bytes_as_str)
        print(rotated(all_bytes_as_str))
        print(ascii_rotated(all_bytes_as_str))
    return


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Comment: your suggestion is very good. the rotated function encode any ascii char and decode easily. But ascii_rotated will fail if decode. for example, when out of range (0x20, 0x7f), you can not judge the source ascii (add -1 or not).

Comment: @Lobo:  I'm afraid I don't understand the problem.  What input is producing an unexpected output?  The goal of `ascii_rotated` is to mangle an ASCII string input while guaranteeing that the output is also an ASCII string (not all bytes are valid ASCII).  It does not attempt to verify that the input is ASCII, or that the output is ASCII.  It does this by altering _only_ bytes in the "printable ASCII" range [0x20, 0x7f)... any byte outside that range is passed through unchanged.  In that sense, "decrypting" and "encrypting" are the same operation, just with different `rotation` parameters.

Comment: @Lobo:  I noticed my text suggested treating spaces as "non-printable" ASCII characters, but that my code treated them as "printable".  I have edited the text to match the code.  Is that what you were talking about?